# Is "open my eyes a slit" grammatical?

Tags: sentence-construction

I read a sentence in Kafka on the shore which was:

> Several times from inside the sleeping bag I open my eyes a slit and peer around the dimly lit room just to be sure no one else is there.

I do get the sense conveyed here but don't think "open my eyes a slit" is grammatical. I think there should have been "as" before a slit in the sentence. Am I right?

Comment: For your information, all of Kafka in English comes from translations from the original German. You might want to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatical. It seems here like *a slit* is functioning as an adverb phrase.

This is similar to *a crack* or *a bit* in these examples:

> He opened the door a crack.

> She sat and pondered a bit.

I'm not sure what this phenomenon is called. I think it is an idiom that only works with a few words.